# First moment inequality and time-average limits

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, stochastic-processes

Suppose $\{A(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ and $\{B(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ are two non-negative stochastic processes such that
$$
\frac{1}{T} \int_{s=0}^T A(s) \, {\rm d} s \stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{\rightarrow} a \in \mathbb R_+, \quad \text{ as } T \to \infty,
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{T} \int_{s=0}^T B(s) \, {\rm d} s \stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{\rightarrow} b \in \mathbb R_+, \quad \text{ as } T \to \infty,
$$
Suppose that $\mathbb E A(t) \geq \mathbb E B(t)$ for every $t \geq 0$. Does this fact imply that $a \geq b$? If yes, how would one prove it?